# QPushButton visual issue

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I have two custom-styled `QPushButton` buttons. Here is the stylesheet for the `Ok` button:

```
QPushButton
{ 
    background-color:#9dce2c;
    border-radius:7px;
    border:1px solid #83c41a;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:4px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
QPushButton:pressed
{
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

Now here's what it looks like:

[image: Ok button]

which is fine. However, if the button is clicked (gets focus), it starts to look like this:

[image: Ok button focused]

Note that slight shadowy rectangle around the text. It looks as if the text is being "selected". When the button loses focus, it starts looking normal again. I suppose it happens because the selected controls get highlighted like this:

[image]

However, I want my button to stay unchanged, no matter whether it's focused or not. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. It turned out to be *very* simple.

The issue was indeed caused by the button receiving focus. All I needed to do is set the button's `focusPolicy` attribute to `NoFocus`. It can be done either in QtDesigner:

[image]

or in the code:

`ui.okButton->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);`

After it's done, the clicks on the button will not cause it to get focus, and the appearance will not change.

Comment: You may get the slight difference in behavior - when you have focus on button you may 'press' it by the Space key, but it all depends on what you need. Personally I always liked the GUIs that can be used by keyboard, so bad that developers overlook this feature these days :(.

Comment: @Kolenda, yes, I'm aware of this. I have a `QLineEdit` on my form, which the user will use to input his stuff. I will track for `Enter` hits in this `QLineEdit`, and force the button press when that happens.

Comment: @Kolenda, that's a good point though, I find it very disappointing not to be able to hit `enter` to complete the filling, too.

Comment: The screenshot you provided is of Qt Designer, not Qt Creator. Creator is an IDE, which can (but not necessarily) integrate Designer

Answer (score 4):

This removes the orange rectangle :

```
QPushButton:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

*PS : You should try to add some style to the focus state like a changed background-color so that this state stays "visible" to the user.*

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try but I think you could fix that by setting `QPushButton:hover` to the same style as `QPushButton`. There's some default style that makes the button red on hover, you just need to find out which one it is (probably `hover`) and override it.

Comment: It doesn't become red on hovering. It becomes so after it's clicked, and remains so until any other control is clicked.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, right, then try the `QPushButton:focus` state.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, or could it be the `:default` state? Logically not but could be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html

I've found parameters like:

```
"selection-color: yellow;"
"selection-background-color: blue;"
```

I haven't tried them but it might be what you need.